# how can I read/scrape the firefox task manager (about:performance) from python?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I have tried to do this with selenium, setting my normal firefox profile as the profile, then loaded the firefox *about:performance* page which should list all the open tabs with memory usage etc., but it only sees the tabs open via selenium. I thought using the same profile would allow me to see tabs opened normally in an already running instance of firefox.

I would like to be able to read the memory usage, energy impact and so on, as displayed in *about:performance*, for each tab for use in my code. Any help or advice greatly appreciated, thanks. The ideal solution for me would use python, but if anything else can get the result I want, I would be very keen to know about it.